# PHP not working with HTML when checking user input

Tags: php, html, user-input

I am trying to check and see if the user has inputted something inside of the HTML page by using PHP and for some reason nothing is coming up on my screen when I test it.

```
...
    <form>
        <label for="age">Enter your age: </label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age">
        </br></br>
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>

<?php
    $theAge;
    if(isset($_GET["submit"])){
        $theAge = $_GET["age"];

        if($theAge == "")
        {
            echo("<p>Please enter an age</p>");
            }
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input type should be submit and not button.

```
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <form>
        <label for="age">Enter your age: </label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age">
        </br></br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes this worked! I was confused because I was trying out exactly what my teacher had and hers worked but mine didn't. And after you said it I noticed she used submit as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're not setting a method on the form, and your check is redundant and not really working either. First off, you need to decide if you want GET or POST. Here's a version using POST:

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
    <label for="age">Enter your age: </label>
    <input type="text" name="age" id="age">
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $theAge = $_POST['age'] ?? '';

    if($theAge == '') {
        echo('<p>Please enter an age</p>');
    } else {
// do something here
    }
?>
```

If you rather wanna use GET, just change the POST to GET in the code.

Note that his uses PHP 7.x notation - if you're using an older version of PHP (you shouldn't), then you'll have to change this line: `$theAge = $_POST['age'] ?? '';` to `$theAge = isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : '';`